# Javascript. Uncaught TypeError: Hashids is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, hashids

Running the code from the tutorial at https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashids

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hashids.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var hashids = new Hashids();
    console.log(hashids.encode(1));

</script>
```

get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Hashids is not a constructor.`

I am running this in a vanilla js app with no modules. just html and js files. If I use `reqire(hasids)` then it pops up with error: `require is not defined`. I need to run this on my app that is coded in regular browser javascript. Please help me run this. 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified from the browser "Network" developer tool that the script is actually being loaded correctly?

Comment: @Pointy Shows up in both sources. and network. I really don't know what is wrong but I really need to get this working.

Comment: @Pointy probably just an issue with the fact that hashids was written for node but im trying to use it regular js

Comment: Well their own documentation advertises it as working exactly as your code expects. Do you have a recent version?

Comment: @Pointy Yes. That is the exact problem. The documentation seems wrong/old. I downloaded hashids.min.js from their dist folder. It would be really great if u could make a dummy browser and test it. I know I am bothering u a bit too much, so u dont have to. But I would be very thanful and appreciative, and it would help me out a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That module's web information is incorrect. When you import the script the way you're doing it, you have to use

```
var hashids = new Hashids.default();
```

You might want to log a Github issue about it; it's clearly misleading as they explicitly tell you to do exactly what your code does.

Comment: how do I add salt ?

Comment: @AbhiBurk pass the salt to the `default` call hence: `new Hashids.default("this is my salt")`

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the answer! just opened an update on the doc for this -- https://github.com/niieani/hashids.js/pull/314